# Reactjs onClick event how to select a specific button from a list

Tags: reactjs

```
var RoomList = React.createClass({
    getInitialState: function() {
        return { liked: false };
    }, 
    handleClick: function(event) {
        this.setState({liked: !this.state.liked});
    },
    render: function() {
        var text = this.state.liked ? 'empty' : 'full';
        var inOffice = this.props.data.map((function(comment, index) {
            return(       
                <button type='button' key={index}  className ={text} onClick={this.handleClick}> 
                {comment.room}  
                </button>
            );
        }).bind(this));
        return (
            <ul className='rooms'>{inOffice}</ul>
        );
    }
});
```

Problem: This is only part of my code... I load a list of 5 value pairs: {"room":101},{room:102}... I create a button for each. When I click on a button, it should change color from red to green or green to red, however, it changes all of the buttons. How can I change the color of just one of my buttons?

Comment: possible duplicate of [react - idiomatic way to remove child](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27217938/react-idiomatic-way-to-remove-child)

Comment: @FakeRainBrigand Components structure looks a little similar but this question address different issue.

Comment: @daniula there's a more accurate duplicate somewhere, but I wasn't able to find it (updating a value in an array in state with a click event based on index), the delete example is just off in how it modifies the array.  Anyway, your answer is the right solution if this is just UI state.

Comment: @Brian Smith do you need every room have its own like/dislike state or  you want only one room to be liked at a time?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create buttons as a separate React Components and handle onClick isolated between them. RoomList becomes just simple list of RoomElement components.

```
var RoomElement = React.createClass({
    getInitialState: function() {
        return { liked: false };
    },
    handleClick: function(event) {
        this.setState({liked: !this.state.liked});
    },
    render: function() {
        return (
            <button type="button" key={index} className={ this.state.liked ? 'empty' : 'full' } onClick={this.handleClick}> 
            {this.props.text}  
            </button>
        );
    }
});

var RoomList = React.createClass({
    render: function() {
        return (
            <ul className="rooms">
            {this.props.data.map(function(comment, index) {
                return <RoomElement key={index} text={comment.room} />
            }, this) }
            </ul>
        );
    }
});
```

Comment: Isn't it an issue that the child holds the state rather than the parent?

Comment: Good point, it's better to keep one state in RoomList and pass value to RoomElement through props and that's how frameworks like Redux are handling it. However, this is unrelated to an issue which was described in question.